# Set a page title in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a simple imageboard and I want the page titles, i.e. those between `<title>` tags, change corresponding to the board I'm actually visiting. E.g. I visit the **/b/** board, and the page title becomes `/b/ - MyChan`. I thought to make it something like this:

```
<% unless current_page?(root_path) %>
    <title>
        <%= @board.title %> - MyChan
    </title>
<% else %>
    <title>MyChan</title>
<% end %>
```

but I'm not sure if that will work

Comment: Yes the above code will work. You can even add a `before_filter` to set title.

Comment: @Sahil excellent, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer already was in my question - the code I provided above,

```
<% unless current_page?(root_path) %>
    <title>
        <%= @board.title %> - MyChan
    </title>
<% else %>
    <title>MyChan</title>
<% end %>
```

works exactly as I need